# Strange Behaviour in DateTime.TryParse

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to Parse a DateTime String "5-5-5-5"  with

```
DateTime.TryParse("5-5-5-5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);
```

I expect this to be converted to

```
5/5/2005 5:00:00 AM
```

But instead it gets converted to

```
5/5/2005 10:30:00 AM.
```

Looks like its interpreting the supplied datetime as GMT. Which is a bit counter-intuitive since I've already specified the `AssumeLocal` flag. Is this a bug in the `DateTime` class?

Comment: Nonsense in, nonsense out. Edit: What is the return value?

Comment: Why is your string in that format? Maybe it should be at least "5-5-5 5:00"?

Comment: you're trying achieve something, doing it wrong, and `Is this a bug in the DateTime class` isn't fare.

Comment: Are you in India by any chance?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Why do I need to AdjustToUniversal exactly? AssumeLocal- If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a local time. Shouldn't this work? I'm trying to understand the issue here.

Comment: If the input string denotes a local time, through a time zone specifier or AssumeLocal, the date and time are converted from the local time to UTC.

Comment: read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Maybe as leppie said this format maybe unsupported. But I cant find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your point and debug the dot net framework code to find out what is happening in the background.

> `TryParse` method is ignoring `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` flag and Only `AdjustToUniversal` flag is processed.

```
if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) != 0) {
            return (AdjustTimeZoneToUniversal(ref result));
        }
        return (AdjustTimeZoneToLocal(ref result, bTimeOnly));
```

> On the other hand `TryParseExact` method is correctly implemented and it has all the required logic to handle `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` flag. See how additional case is handled in this implementation.

```
            // If AssumeLocal or AssumeLocal is used, there will always be a kind specified. As in the
            // case when a time zone is present, it will default to being local unless AdjustToUniversal
            // is present. These comparisons determine whether setting the kind is sufficient, or if a
            // time zone adjustment is required. For consistentcy with the rest of parsing, it is desirable
            // to fall through to the Adjust methods below, so that there is consist handling of boundary
            // cases like wrapping around on time-only dates and temporarily allowing an adjusted date
            // to exceed DateTime.MaxValue
            if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) != 0) {
                if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) != 0) {
                    result.flags |= ParseFlags.TimeZoneUsed;
                    result.timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalUtcOffset(result.parsedDate, TimeZoneInfoOptions.NoThrowOnInvalidTime);
                }
                else {
                    result.parsedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(result.parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal) != 0) {
                if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) != 0) {
                    result.parsedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(result.parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    result.flags |= ParseFlags.TimeZoneUsed;
                    result.timeZoneOffset = TimeSpan.Zero;
                }
            }
            else {
                // No time zone and no Assume flags, so DateTimeKind.Unspecified is fine
                Contract.Assert(result.parsedDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified, "result.parsedDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified");
                return true;
            }
```

On side note, It is fun debugging Dot Net framework code. If you are interested then follow steps from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html).

Answer (score 1):

When time zone is NOT specified, you must explicitly indicate the time zone using `AssumeLocal` or `AssumeUniversal` and then convert it to UTC using `AdjustToUniversal`:

```
DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
```

or

```
DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
```

Read more on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0) and pay attention to the last sentence:

> ### **AdjustToUniversal**:
>
> If the input string denotes a **local time**, through a time zone specifier or `AssumeLocal`, the date and time are converted **from the local time to UTC**.
>
> If the input string denotes a **UTC time**, through a time zone specifier or `AssumeUniversal`, **no conversion occurs**.
>
> If the input string **does not denote** a local or UTC time, **no conversion occurs** and the resulting Kind property is Unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the desired result as :

> 5/5/2005 5:00:00 AM

[**AdjustToUniversal**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) :

Date and time are returned as a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). If the input string denotes a local time, through a time zone specifier or AssumeLocal, the date and time are converted from the local time to UTC. If the input string denotes a UTC time, through a time zone specifier or AssumeUniversal, no conversion occurs. If the input string does not denote a local or UTC time, no conversion occurs and the resulting Kind property is Unspecified.
This value cannot be used with RoundtripKind.

use the below code as `AdjustToUniversal`:

```
DateTime result;
dt= DateTime.TryParse("5-5-5-5" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal , out result);
```

Comment: This seems to work but why do I need to AdjustToUniversal exactly? AssumeLocal- If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a local time. Shouldn't this work? I'm trying to understand the issue here.

Comment: @gawicks try giving 5-5-5-0 ? it will show result as 5:30 (+5.30 for india).then if 5-5-5-5 it just adds 5 hours and gives you the result 10.30,that is the reason Aron commented

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. Let me rephrase the question this way. 5-5-5 5:00 + AssumeLocal = 5/5/2005 5:00:00 AM  (This is expected) . But 5-5-5-5 + AssumeLocal = 5/5/2005 10:30:00 AM (This is strange)

Comment: How : 5-5-5 5:00 + AssumeLocal = 5/5/2005 5:00:00 AM ? you cannot expect the result ! its not bug even

Comment: sorry but I'm not clear. What do you mean I cannot expect the result? It's how the DateTime class behaves currently. I'm simply asking why.

Comment: Is such a limitation documented somewhere?

Comment: It gives 5:30:00 AM.  And 5-5-5 0:00 or 5/5/5 0:00 gives 12:00AM. see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` is what you're looking for.